# Using cscope to search for patterns with spaces

Tags: cscope

I have the following problem. Consider this line:

```
uint8_t status = 0x00;
```

Now if I want to search for the occurence for the status, I will get LOADS of references (nearly every module uses some sort of status).

```
:cs find s status
```

Now, I thought that the best idea would be to search for: `extern uint8_t status` which will narrow down my search results (a little...)

```
:cs find e extern uint8_t status
```

Unfortunatelly `cscope` with `egrep` doesn't allow that. How should my call to `cs find e` look like, so that I will the occurence of `extern uint8_t status`?
I have tried the following (omitting the obvious `extern uint8_t`...)

```
:cs find e status =
:cs find e status\s=
:cs find e status[:space:]=
:cs find e status[[:space:]]=
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that the following works:

```
:cs find e status[ ]=
```